# How to read JSON object in kotlin with Volle Android Studio?

Tags: json, kotlin, google-api, android-volley, get-request

I'm using volley to read a Get Request from the Google Places API and I want to get some information from this JSON OUTPUT:

```
"results": [
{
"business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 25.7239497,
      "lng": -100.1915475
    },
    "viewport": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 25.7252242302915,
        "lng": -100.1902086197085
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 25.7225262697085,
        "lng": -100.1929065802915
      }
    }
},
"icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/restaurant-71.png",
"icon_background_color": "#FF9E67",
"icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/restaurant_pinlet",
"name": "El Texanito",
"opening_hours": {},
"photos": [],
"place_id": "ChIJJdu3AjbqYoYRPJyEgQwBT-0",
"plus_code": {},
"price_level": 2,
"rating": 4,
"reference": "ChIJJdu3AjbqYoYRPJyEgQwBT-0",
"scope": "GOOGLE",
"types": [],
"user_ratings_total": 563,
"vicinity": "Boulevard Acapulco #141, Josefa Zozaya, Guadalupe"
},
```

My kotlin Code:

```
fun methodToGetInfo(){
    tbUsuarios?.removeAllViews()
    var queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?fields=price_level&location=25.7299374%2C-100.2096866&radius=2500&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyDV6aFItX960hrbAaI229-8iDa3xTZ-RXU"
    var myJsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
        Response.Listener {
                response ->  try{
            var myJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results")
            for(i in 0 until myJsonArray.length()){
                var myJSONObject = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val registro = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row_np,null,false)
                val colName = registro.findViewById<View>(R.id.columnaNombre) as TextView
                val colPrice = registro.findViewById<View>(R.id.columnaEmail) as TextView
                val colLatitude = registro.findViewById<View>(R.id.colEditar)
                val colBorrar = registro.findViewById<View>(R.id.colBorrar)

                colName.text= myJSONObject.getString("name")
                Log.d(TAG, "Nombre:  ${ myJSONObject.getString("name")}" )

                Log.d(TAG, "Rating:  ${ myJSONObject.getString("price_level")}" )
                colPrice.text=myJSONObject.getString("price_level")

                Log.d(TAG, "Latitude: ${myJSONObject.getString("location")}")




              

                tbUsuarios?.addView(registro)

            }
```

I can easily get information like the name, price rating, place_id, etc but when I need to get data inside some properties like for example lat, I am getting an error.

I know that simply searching for "lat" is wrong because I need to travel "geometry" -> "location" -> "lat"

I want to know how to travel through these properties and get that information

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the type is [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONObject), you can use something like

```
myJSONObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat")
```

If the fields aren't guaranteed to be present, use [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls):

```
myJSONObject.getJSONObject("geometry")?.getJSONObject("location")?.getString("lat")
```

Of course if you want to access more than one property from the same path it can make sense to use a local variable too, e.g.

```
val location = myJSONObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
val latitude = location.getString("lat")
val longitude = location.getString("lng")
```